# Erlang install on Freebsd 10 on Amazon ec2

Tags: erlang, freebsd

I'm trying to install erlang on amazon ec2 - on freebsd 10:

```
fetch http://www.erlang.org/download/otp_src_17.0.tar.gz
gunzip -c otp_src_17.0.tar.gz | tar xf -
cd otp_src_17.0
./configure --disable-hipe
gmake
gmake install
```

and I get the following error:

> configure: error: Perl is required to generate v2 to v1 mib converter script
>   configure: error: /bin/sh '/usr/home/ec2-user/otp_src_17.0/lib/snmp/./configure' failed for snmp/.
>   configure: error: /bin/sh '/usr/home/ec2-user/otp_src_17.0/lib/configure' failed for lib

How do I avoid this error and install erlang on freebsd 10?

Answer (score 1):

Use either packages ("pkg install erlang"), or ports (cd /usr/ports/lang/erlang && make install).  Software often requires patches to make it run correctly, and ports/packages take care of that.  They also automatically take care of dependencies, and that seems to be the root cause of your problem: you don't have perl installed.

Comment: trasz thank it's work, by default install erlang 16.b , how i install erlang 17?

Comment: comman - cd /usr/ports/lang/erlang && make install - give me error /usr/ports/lang/erlang: No such file or directory.

Comment: @soft-developer I'm afraid you're out of luck - you just need to wait until the newer version is available.

As for the "No such file or directory" problem - do you actually have ports installed?  Note you can install it either from binary package (pkg install ruby), or via ports; use "portsnap fetch extract" to install the ports tree.

Answer (score 1):

So, I think you can install package
I have FreeBSD storage 10.1-RELEASE-p16 FreeBSD 10.1-RELEASE-p16 #0
And simple way is `pkg install erlang`

Answer (score 0):

There's [kerl](https://github.com/yrashk/kerl) which is an excellent project for building and maintaining all Erlang/OTP versions